# angular2: style md-dialog

Tags: html, css, angular

i am trying to style md-dialog to be as in image1
[image: Image 1]
         Image 1

image 1 css class :

```
   .mat-dialog-container {
        box-shadow: 0 11px 15px -7px rgba(0,0,0,.2), 0 24px 38px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.14), 0 9px 46px 8px rgba(0,0,0,.12);
        display: block;
        padding: 24px;
        border-radius: 2px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        overflow: hidden;
        background: white;
        width: 500px;
        height: 162px;
    }
```

but the browser overrides my style i always find that the browser apply this css class to the component and override my style

```
.mat-dialog-container {
    box-shadow: 0 11px 15px -7px rgba(0,0,0,.2), 0 24px 38px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.14), 0 9px 46px 8px rgba(0,0,0,.12);
    display: block;
    padding: 24px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    overflow: auto;
    max-width: 80vw;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

so the dialog be like image 2  :
[image]
Image 2

i added my style to the css file as `mat-dialog-container` and also i named it as host like this

```
host:{
            box-shadow: 0 11px 15px -7px rgba(0,0,0,.2), 0 24px 38px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.14), 0 9px 46px 8px rgba(0,0,0,.12);
            display: block;
            padding: 24px;
            border-radius: 2px;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            overflow: hidden;
            background: white;
            width: 500px;
            height: 162px;
        }
```

but it is always get overridden

the name of my dialog is `discard-pop-up` and the code is as following :

discard-pop-up.component.html :

```
  <h1 md-dialog-title>Discard Changes</h1>
<div md-dialog-content>Are you sure you want to discard changes ?</div>
<div md-dialog-actions>
  <button md-button (click)="dialogRef.close('Option 1')">Yes</button>
  <button md-button (click)="dialogRef.close('Option 2')">No</button>
</div>
```

discard-pop-up.component.ts :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {MdDialog, MdDialogRef} from '@angular/material';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-discard-pop-up',
  templateUrl: './discard-pop-up.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./discard-pop-up.component.css']
})
export class DiscardPopUpComponent implements OnInit {
  popUpContent:string;
  popUpTitle:string;
  constructor(public dialogRef: MdDialogRef<DiscardPopUpComponent>) {}

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

discard-pop-up.component.css :

```
   .mat-dialog-container {
        box-shadow: 0 11px 15px -7px rgba(0,0,0,.2), 0 24px 38px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.14), 0 9px 46px 8px rgba(0,0,0,.12);
        display: block;
        padding: 24px;
        border-radius: 2px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        overflow: hidden;
        background: white;
        width: 500px;
        height: 162px;
    }
```

and i am oppining it inside another component by calling this function :

```
     openDialog() {
    let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DiscardPopUpComponent, {



    //   padding: '24px',
    // border-radius: '2px',
    // box-sizing: 'border-box',
    // overflow: 'hidden',
    // width: '542px',
    // height: '160px',
    // background: 'white',
});
     dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {



       this.selectedPopUpOption = result;
     });
  }
}
```

Comment: Is your dialog part of an external library?

Comment: no it is not, i am just changing the original style by adjusting width and height and adding a white background

Comment: can you somehow create a wroking code?

Comment: Is it a directive? Someone is changing those styles, we have to find who is changing them

Comment: I think you would probably receive an answer faster if you created a plunker to go with your question :)

Comment: I am facing the same problem